# get to post google map gdownloadurl

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is the javascript.

```
var url = "http://google.com/gmap.jsp?uid="+userid+"&lat="+lat;
GDownloadUrl(url,function(doc){});
```

how to change from get to post?
any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think this it

```
GDownloadUrl("http://google.com/gmap.jsp",function(doc){},"uid="+userid+"&lat="+lat");
```